# Search an array for missing information

Tags: java, arrays, contains

I need to find a way to search the email and find out if the email field in an array is missing "@", "." or has a blank space.

So far I've found http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_contains.htm , and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_contains.htm . Which is good but still confuses me.

I have a get method for the email (getEmail) and Im trying to figure out how it would loop through the myRoster array and print out each email missing that information. Any clarification or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share the code that you are working with in an [edit]. A simple "for loop" and a string comparison is all you really should need. `ArrayList.contains` is not needed

Comment: Suggested title: Search an array of strings for a character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the email string with boolean flags set to false for each character you are looking for.  If you find the character you are searching for set the flag to true.  At the end of the loop if the flag is still false the character wasn't found.

For example..

```
Boolean atFound = false;
Boolean periodFound = false;
Boolean spaceFound = false;
For (integer cnt = 0; cnt < email.length; cnt ++)
{
    If (email [cnt].compareTo ("@") == 0)
        atFound = true;
    If (email [cnt].compareTo (".") == 0)
        periodFound = true;
    If (email [cnt].compareTo (" ") == 0)
        spaceFound = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help and suggestions! I'll have to play around with both answers but I think for this Luke's answer will be the best route.

Answer (score 3):

A previous poster pointed out using "boolean flags" while iterating the String. This is okay if you're doing some microscopic performance optimizations, but I think it's a bit of an overoptimization compared to using some simpler methods like `String#indexOf`.

```
public boolean hasValidEmail(String email) {
    int at = email.indexOf('@');
    //first ensures '@' exists, then that '.' is after '@', and lastly checks for no space
    return at > 0 && email.lastIndexOf('.') > at && !email.contains(' ');
}
```

It's definitely not perfect, and there are attempts at regex validations for such things out there, but for a simple check it's more than sufficient.

If you really did want to do the string iteration only once, you could iterate `#toCharArray`. Though I'd recommend just using direct char comparison over `#compareTo`:

```
char c = /* some char */;
if (c == '@') {
    //etc
}
```

In short, "premature optimization is the root of all evil". It's certainly fine to optimize but there are better, more modern methods like profiling of finding out why code is slow.

Comment: The whole email validation problem turns out to be way more complex than you would think.  Turns out you can't really write a regex that fully validates to the RFC standards.  I couldn't find any public libraries that seemed acceptable either.  The more restrictive solutions tend to be fragile, many fail to accept the new TLDs.  So you are better off with a simple solution like the one above or a simple regex like: 

[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]

Then send them an email and require some action, a time honored approach.

Comment: Indeed, I think one of the longer ones was something ridiculous like 300 lines or so? There's literally a webpage somewhere comparing various regexes out there and they just get.... big.

Comment: The biggest sin would be denying a user service.  I just learned TLDs now accept non-english character sets like Japanes Kanji.  So I repent of even my simple regex.